# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') - Tried everything but won't work

Tags: python, numpy

I used standardscaler on a dataset to normalise features and run a K means over it, but cannot complete the operation because I got this error.

I have tried:

- `np.isnan(x.any())` -> result false
- `np.isfinite(x.all())` -> result true

I cannot find the issue in the dataset.

Comment: `np.isnan(x.any())` Shouldn't that be `np.isnan(x).any()`, and `np.isfinite(x).all()` for the other?

Comment: I should probably explain: `x.any()` and `x.all()` evaluate the truthyness of the elements of the array, and return a bool. `np.isnan()` will never return True for a bool, and neither will `np.isfinite()`.

Comment: I had nulls! fixed! thanks!